# Is the set on which an integrable function less than zero measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

For a measurable space $(T,\tau,\mu)$, let $f:T\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be an integrable function.

What is the condition for the set $\{t\in T:f(t)<0\}$ be measurable?

It would be really grateful if someone can also give me a source for the answer.

Comment: By definition, integrable functions are measurable, so your set is.

Comment: Common definitions of a measurable function imply that the inverse image of an open set such as $(-\infty, 0)$ by a measurable function is a measurable set.  See, e.g., Baby Rudin 11.15.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, the set is measurable if $$ \{ t\in T \colon f(t) < 0 \} \in \tau .$$

Since $f$ is  [Lebesgue-integrable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Domain_of_integration), it is per definition also measurable. The condition that $f$ is measurable is equivalent to
$$ \{ t \in T \colon f(t) < \alpha \} \in \tau $$
for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Special_measurable_functions). Since $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, your set is measurable.